# Why is my QListView empty in IconMode?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QListView` displaying data from a custom `ListModel`. Everything seems to be working fine in the "regular" view mode (`ListMode`) -- icons, labels, drag/drop, etc. As soon as I change it to `IconMode` nothing displays.

Here's the relevant code. I've left out the main window and any other cruft, but if it helps I'll include it.

```
# Model
class TheModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, items = [], parent = None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.__items = items

    def appendItem(self, item):
        self.__items.append(item)

        # item was added to end of list, so get that index
        index = len(self.__items) - 1

        # data was changed, so notify
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.__items)

    def data(self, index, role):
        image = self.__items[index.row()]

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            # name
            return image.name

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            # icon
            return QtGui.QIcon(image.path)

        return None

# ListView
class TheListView(QtGui.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_DragDropListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(48, 48))
        self.setViewMode(QtGui.QListView.IconMode)

    # ...
```

Comment: I remember there being an issue on a project I was working on with PySide where I think we had to set the [``gridSize``](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QListView.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QListView.gridSize) on the ``QListView`` to get icons to display - you may wish to try that.

Comment: @Lattyware No luck with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, worth a try. Good luck with PySide, QT is powerful, but I found it awkward to work with - I think because it's such a thin wrapper and doesn't feel at all Pythonic. Plus the docs are not great.

Comment: Thanks! I moved to PySide from wxPython and it feels like a significant step up. Having said that, I'm still very much a beginner with either.

Comment: Where are you setting the model?  It's not in the code you pasted.

Comment: @ecatmur I'm trying to keep logic out of `TheListView`, so  the model is being set elsewhere (when setting up the main window). I guess it's irrelevant, though, as everything is fine outside of `IconMode`.

Comment: Well, `IconMode` works fine for me using similar code.  If you post an SSCCE it might help to see where the bug is.

Comment: @ecatmur Thanks for the suggestion: I found that my SSCCE worked too, so I curiously delved into it and finally found the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some heavy debugging, I found that `data()` was never getting called. The problem was with the way I was inserting data into the model: `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` should be called. The new method resembles the following:

```
def appendItem(self, item):
    index = len(self.__items)

    self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), index, index)
    self.__items.append(item)
    self.endInsertRows()
```

Despite the old method not using using `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()`, `ListMode` worked just fine. That's what threw me off: I still don't think it should have worked. Quirk?

Comment: `ListMode` or `IconMode` shouldn't matter for the behavior you are seeing. You're probably doing something different each time. By the way, your `beginInsertRows` is wrong. First parameter should be `parent` and since it's a list, it doesn't have any parent. So an invalid `QModelIndex`. The others should be `start` and `end` (inclusive). If it's just one item, `start` and `end` would be same. So the correct form should be `beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), insert_row, insert_row)`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I couldn't find much detailing exactly what the method expects. Regarding the behaviour, it is logical that it shouldn't change just because the view is formatted differently, but it does. And it seems directly related to the way items are added. If you find a better explanation, though, please do post an answer!

Comment: Well, looking at your original post, I just realized that you're emitting just integers with `dataChanged`. That can't work. That is simply an error. They should be `QModelIndex`. So I don't know how you managed to get it 'work' with that model.